# How to modify echo'd variable already called in PHP?

Tags: php, function, variables

In the following code, is there a way to modify the contents of a variable after it has been called? In this really simple (and pointless) example, when $foo is called, I wish for it to echo 'baryay', not 'bar' WITHOUT needing to call changefoo() before hand. changefoo must be called after.

```
<?php

changefoo(){
   global $foo,
   $foo .= 'yay';
}

$foo = 'bar';
echo $foo;

changefoo();


?>
```

Awaiting general coding method harassment and suggestions.

Comment: Even with the echo being after your code will **never** echo `baryay`

Comment: It will never echo will never echo baryay

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking. You don't "call" a variable.

Comment: code edited above. Should make a little more sence.

Comment: @David - It's alright to use pseudo-code in your questions but please don't use pseudo-code that resembles real PHP code.

Comment: The point of this question is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Once you've written something to the output, you can hardly go back and change it. You need to restructure your flow to match your needs.

Think of it like an actual printer. If you print something on a piece of paper, even if the page is not done printing yet, you can't go back and modify what you printed.

Answer (score 3):

If it's the result of an `echo` statement, it's no longer a variable. You can alter your scripts output with regular output buffering functions, no matter where it comes from:

```
<?php

function changefoo(){
   global $foo;
   $foo = 'blah';
}

ob_start();
$foo = 'bar';
echo $foo;

changefoo();
ob_end_clean();
echo $foo;

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I **do not** believe that is possible.

---

Also try **not** to use `global`s. just pass the variable in:

```
function changefoo(&$foo){
   $foo .= 'yay';
}

$foo = 'bar';

changefoo($foo);

echo $foo; //baryay
```

Answer (score 2):

No, once it is echoed, you couldn't change what is displayed on screen without using javascript/jquery.  If you want it to echo "baryay", you would need to write:

`echo $foo."yay";`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but here's an idea.

This will echo "bar" then change it to "blah" after 5 secconds

```php
<?php
ob_start(); // output buffering on
$foo = 'bar'; // set $foo initially
echo "<span id='foo'>$foo</div>"; // echo $foo along with some HTML needed later

sleep(5); // wait 5 seconds for demonstration purposes

$foo = 'blah'; // set $foo again
ob_end_clean(); // output buffering off
echo "<script>document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = $foo;</script>"; // outputs JS that changes the DOM innerHTML.
```